# Snowflake DIV0 returns different result than regular division

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why are these results different, comparing Snowflake division vs DIV0? It appears DIV0 is rounding down instead of up. Is there any way to make the DIV0 return the same number as the other results?

**Snowflake query:**

```
SELECT 75026 / 99999 AS divide_by, 
       DIV0(75026, 99999) AS div_0, 
       NVL(75026 / NULLIF(99999, 0), 0) AS div_nvl
```

**Snowflake result:**

```
    DIVIDE_BY   DIV_0       DIV_NVL  
    0.750268    0.750267    0.750268
```

**Calculator result:**

```
0.7502675026750268
```

Comment: Yeah weird, although it's not the first time I have seen similar functions having varying decimal precisions and rounding in Snowflake. I would open up a ticket with them. The `nvl` based approach is the way to go if you ask me

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can implement `NVL` based approach

```
set num=75026;
set den=0;

select iff($den=0,0,$num/$den)
```